# EF Core 3.1 - build tree structure from different entities

Tags: entity-framework-core

Im developing a warehouse system, in which I have Pack and Load entities.
The real life structure looks something like that:

Warehouse:

- Pack1

  - Load1
- Pack2

  - Pack3

    - Load2
  - Pack4

    - Pack5

      - Load3
    - Pack6

      - Load4

etc.

As you can see, the Packs can be inside other Packs, and those can be inside yet other Packs, and at the end of the chains, there are Loads.
Pack and Load entities are quite different, the only thing that they have in common is that they are a part of the mentioned tree structure.
I was trying to enable that by creating a base abstract class (StorageEntity), from which Packs
and Loads can inherit.

The StorageEntity class would have fields that allow using the objects as tree nodes:

```
  public abstract class StorageEntity
    {
        public int ContainerId { get; set; }
        public virtual StorageEntity Container { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StorageEntity> Content { get; set; }
    }
```

My problems:

1. I don't have an idea how to make this work with the Entity Framework. I was trying to use fluid API to configure the mechanism like so:

   ```
    modelBuilder.Entity<StorageEntity>()
                    .HasMany(p => p.Content)
                    .WithOne(s => s.Container);
   ```

but when I try to add the migration I get an error:

```
The entity type 'StorageEntity' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'.
```

If I add HasNoKey() to the configuration I get a null reference exception instead.

2. Is that approach even the proper one? What are alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

This is very common Node structure, as seens with Folders & Files.

Usually you'd declare one root folder (top level node) with registered subfolders and files as collections (subnodes) on the aggregate entity or letting the root folder be the aggregate.

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntity 
{
  public long Id {get; set;} 
}

public class Pack : BaseEntity
{
  public long StorageEntityId {get; set;}
  public virtual StorageEntity ParentStorageEntity {get; set;}

  public virtual Pack ParentPack {get; set;} 

  public virtual ICollection<Pack> SubPacks {get; set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Load> Loads {get; set;}
}

public class Load : BaseEntity
{
  // Load entity's props here
}

public class StorageEntity : BaseEntity
{
  public virtual Pack RootPack {get; set;}
}
```

all your Database entities should have a primary key.
and this should and would scaffold your migration correctly without configuration. Though for easier understanding on what is actually configured on the database I can only recommend using explicit fluent configuration for EF Core.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<StorageEntity>()
  .HasOne(t => t.RootPack)
  .WithOne(t => t.ParentStorageEntity)
  .HasForeignKey<Pack>(t => t.ParentStorageEntityId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Pack>()
  .HasMany(t => t.SubPacks)
  .WithOne(t => t.ParentPack);

modelBuilder.Entity<Pack>
  .HasMany(t => t.Loads)
  .WithOne();

modelBuilder.Entity<Pack>
```

querying it can be a bit tricky,
but you could do something like

```cs
var flattenedPacks = await _context.Packs.Where(t => t.ParentStorageEntityId == storageId).ToListAsync();
var flattenedLoads = await _context.Loads.Where(t => t.ParentStorageEntityId == storageId).ToListAsync();
// assemble them in a map method or use changetracking through EF core 

var rootPack = flattenedPacks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ParentPack == null);

root packs structure should now because of EF Core's changetracking have the correct structure. :o)
```

Comment: Im sorry but I don't understand what is going on here. The whole point of the solution should be to use fields that are shared through the base class (StorageEntity), without defining new fields in derived classes (like you did in the Pack class). Why should we define ParentStorageEntity and ParentPack in Pack? Why to use two separate lists for Loads and SubPacks? What if we want to add third, fourth etc. object type to the tree structure?

Comment: Sorry might be a misunderstanding on my behalf then. If the case is you want to have 
Pack => Pack => Load => Money => Oranges structure then you could use inheritance. which EF Core can do with a discriminator column telling which type it is 
[ef core inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) 
though i'm not a big fan of this implementation because tables do get quite messy when having more than a few "NodeTypes" 
You could consider having a NodeEntity with dynamic fields

Comment: Exactly - I was doing some research on my own and I found out that I could use ef inheritance (table per hierarchy type) to achieve that. But as you say - this looks quite messy and in my case, it's gonna produce a lot of not-used cells in the table. I wonder if there is a better way.